# Cassandra: Does node add/remove requires all cluster nodes be present?

Tags: cassandra

When a new node added, due to the even distribution of the new tokens,
the current nodes of the ring should migrate data to this new node.

So, does it requires all nodes be present? If not, then if some nodes
are down, then it will miss the data migration of those parts, how and
when to fix it? When those nodes come back?

Similarly, the node removal would migrate its data to other nodes, so
it seems that all other nodes must be present, otherwise it would lost
data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra requires all nodes to be present. I tried adding a node when another node was down and received this error:

```
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/172.17.0.2). If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/172.17.0.2). If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getAllRangesWithStrictSourcesFor(RangeStreamer.java:275)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:158)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:83)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1212)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:891)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:657)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:570)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:346)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:569)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:697)
ERROR 09:53:37 Exception encountered during startup
```

Same happens when I try to add node in different dc.

As for removing a node. Decomission only works if all replicas are up. Decomission will start by streaming all data to new replicas, if streaming fails then decomission fails.

```
$ nodetool decommission
error: Stream failed
-- StackTrace --
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    ...
```

You can still force a remove by shutting the node down and doing `nodetool removenode`. This will not stream data but will remove node from cluster. Use with caution.

There is also `nodetool assasinate` if neither decomission or removenode works.

Comment: Thanks for your information! If node add/remove requires other nodes alive, then the feasibility of cluster seems bad. Do you think so?

Comment: @kingluo Not really. Whenever a node is down in Cassandra then the cluster is in a bad state. To safely add or remove a node the cluster needs to be in a good state with all nodes up. However, just as there is `removenode` command for removing a node when the cluster is in a bad state there are also ways to adding nodes in a bad state. If you only have one node down and you want to replace that node you set the `-Dcassandra.replace_address` variable in cassandra-env.sh.

Comment: You can also add a node without streaming any data (but beware, this node will still take requests) by setting `auto_bootstrap` to false. You will then have to run repair afterwards. This doesn't make any sense though since this will jeopordize consistency until repair has finished. `auto_bootstrap` should only be used when initiailizing a fresh cluster without data. But of course, depending on your use case it could have other uses.